# jQuery append does not consider CSS of the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried to add an item to a main div when clicking in the button add item, this should (every time) add a new line ( a text input), to the main content. This works fine.

The problem is that the text input has some css (some width and height...), which is not loading when adding it with jQuery, so the add works fine but it shows a "normal" unstyled text input, not mine (witch is styled).

here my HTML.

```
                            <fieldset class="lodging-info-fieldset" id="all_field">
                            <legend>Gage sur &eacutequipement projet</legend>                               

                            <div class="panel-heading score_pannel">
                            <ul class="panel-heading-fieldset">
                                <li>D&eacutesignation</li>
                                <li>Valeur</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group" id="extended">
                            <div class="col50 left  ">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="designation"
                                    placeholder="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col50 left  ">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="valeur"
                                    placeholder="">
                            </div>
                        </div>


                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="add_plus">
                                    <a id="add_pluss"  class='add_plus'>add item </a>
                                    </div>

                                </div>  

                </fieldset>
```

and my jQuery append function:

```
addLigne : function(event) {
                            $("#all_field")
                            .append(
                                '<div class="form-group">'
                              + '<div class="col50 left">'
                              + '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="designation">'
                              + '</div></div>');

            },
```

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you are styling it (we need to view your CSS code), but you are duplicating and N-plicating the same ID element, and is not good practice because you can't access to this element with a correct code (maybe with cruft but is not clean and properly). 
Please, think about it and try to change ids with a unique string, like numbers for example.

```
addLigne : function(event) {
    $("#all_field")
        .append(
              '<div class="form-group">'
            + '<div class="col50 left">'
            + '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="designation_'+ ($('input[id^="designation_"]).length + 1) +'">'
            + '</div></div>');

},
```

When you show us your CSS we can help you with your real problem.

Good luck